# Whitespace/Margin between <table> and <h1> of a <form> element

Tags: css, html, html-table, forms

There is a huge amount of whitespace between `<table>` and `<h1>` both of which are in a form element. As soon as I remove the `<table>` element, this whitespace goes. I am using `<table>` element to align elements to a form. Can someone explain why this is happening?

```html
<form>
  <h2>Form Heading goes here</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="f_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="l_name"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Step 1, don't use tables for layout, use CSS. Use tables for tabular data. This isn't 1997 anymore.

Comment: Make sure there isn't any padding or margin on your `<h1>` or `<table>` elements. You can remove with `<table style="marign:0; padding:0;">`, same for the `<h1>` if that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the h2 tag adds margin under it. The following CSS will remove that space.

**CSS**

```
h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove the default margin of `<h2>`tag.

```css
h2{
margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>Form Heading goes here</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>First Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="f_name"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Last Name</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="l_name"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```